# Get back to un-differenced data after forecast?

Tags: r, diff, arima

I am predicting 4 quarters using an ARIMA model of differentiated variables.
However, I am unable to get back the adjusted values i.e. expected predicted values that are aligned with the original values.

Below is my code:

```
fit<-arima(Y, order = c(1, 0, 1),seasonal = list(order = c(0L, 0L, 0L), period = NA), xreg = training, include.mean = TRUE, method = "CSS",SSinit = "Rossignol2011",0, optim.method = "L-BFGS-B", kappa = 1e6)

x<-predict(fit,n.ahead = 4,newxreg = testing)

diffinv(x,lag=1,xi=Y[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let "xd" denote the differenced data and "x" denote the original data. Then xd[n]=x[n+1]-x[n]. Therefore, x[n+1]=x[n]+xd[n]. If you add the first element of first difference forecast to the real data with the same indice, then you will get the next real data forecast.